# Running a script at Windows 7 or 2008 shutdown

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, scripting

Is there any way to run script before the computer running Windows 7 or 2008 shuts down without using `local group policy editor or domain based policy`? Regedit tool should be OK if possible.

Comment: Do you mean the local group policy editor or domain based policy?

Comment: Yes sorry for the weak description.

Comment: All that `regedit` would do is directly manipulate the registery keys that the local security policy or group policy consoles would. I recommend using those tools instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown

this is the location I think you are looking for.

Comment: When I go to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\" I do not see any "Scripts" key under Windows 7.

Comment: do this use the local policies tool to create the proper key then just copy the results.

Comment: I can seem to be able to fined Local Policy Tool. Only thing I have is Local Security Policy Tool.

Comment: MMC... File... Add/Remove Snap-in... Group Policy Object Editor... Add... Local Computer... Finish... OK